# How to get the parent component's name with Angular 13?

Tags: angular, angular13

I'm trying to get clicks information from each of my app's buttons, so i've added some attributes to all the buttons - and i grab them by the following example:

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
   handleDocumentClicks(event) {

   const elm = event.closest("[audit-clicks]");
   const elmData = elm.getAttribute('audit-data');
   const elmParentComponent = event.closest(??????); /// how to grab html component type?

   console.log(elmParentComponent);
}
```

All is working well - except i need to grab the parent component name also, so i was thinking perhaps angular components got a special generic selector that i could use, besides the explicit name.

Answer (score 0):

sorry that I post an answer but I am not allowed to comment yet.

You can read the parent element props like this:

```
const elmParentComponent = elm.parentElement.tagName;
```

But I am not aware that you could access the component class name from an element.

Comment: thanks - it's only one level up - that's why .closest() works better - but not for what i'm looking for